# How to represent shopping cart values?

Tags: shopping-cart

I'm in the process of creating a shopping cart, I have these value informations to show:

- Discount: % or $ of discount. **only shows when user insert gift code*
- Subtotal: All item values
- Shipping: Shipping cost
- Total: All items + shipping cost

In which order should I display those values? Also, when using a discount value, where/how should I apply those calculations?

Currently I'm using as shown on the image below:

[image]

As you can see, first I show how much is the discount (both in % and in $), after that I show the `subtotal` and already apply the discount calculation. Is this the best way to do this?

Or should I apply the discount calculation only in the `Total` line? Or what other solution should I consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the discounts apply per item, show it per item and indicate whether it's a sale price, a quantity price break, or something else.  If there is no discount, don't repeat the list price because that will simply muddy the water.

If the discount applies to the total, do it only at the total, and with the same type of explanatory label:  you want the buyer to know why the discount occurred so they know whether, and how, they can get it again.

Comment: It's applied to the total, but not considering the shipping cost. Only the total based on the items selected.

Comment: Then you're good:  show the reduction under the list-price total, and the net price under that.

Comment: I meant "net price before shipping" of course.  The shipping would be the next item down, and the total net (the one under the double line) at the bottom.

Comment: In other words, just as you're now doing it, but without the repeat of the list price if the item is not discounted.

Comment: As I said in the question, the "Discount" line only shows when the user enters a valid gift card. Just a matter to change the calculation and add the discount on the "Total" line.

Comment: We might be talking at crossed purposes.  I'm looking at the smaller, slightly greyed $10.00 under the larger, black $10.00.  It appears to repeat the list price, and it's not at all obvious (to me, anyway) why.

Comment: Just as a side question, do you really want the "trash bin" association for the goods? :-)   I'd probably use an "x" for the purpose.

Comment: about the double $10 (still thinking about it) but the small is the single item value, the black one is the quantity * item value. if it was 2 iitems, that would be$ 20/$10. also, great suggedtion about the trash/X